# set OnItemClickListener to ListView

Tags: android, listview

Its my code:

```
 ListView lv=getListView();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    !!!  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",jsonlist.get(position).get("title"));
                intent.putExtra("description",jsonlist.get(position).get("description"));
                intent.putExtra("description",jsonlist.get(position).get("description"));
                intent.putExtra("url",jsonlist.get(position).get("image"));
startActivity(intent);
```

problem is whem Im try to set OnItemClickListener to lv.How can I initialize lv? I have Activity extends ListActivity.I can't find lv for id, because ListView has id=android:id/list. I have adapter,that used setListAdapter(adapter) and all.How can I set listener for lv?

Comment: Why not put a listView in Xml & findviewById in your java code ?

Comment: Post your XML layout file and method: `getListView()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all initialize your lv in onCreate(), and do like below,

```
  ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
        //Supposing your listview is from android package
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    !!!  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",jsonlist.get(position).get("title"));
                intent.putExtra("description",jsonlist.get(position).get("description"));
                intent.putExtra("description",jsonlist.get(position).get("description"));
                intent.putExtra("url",jsonlist.get(position).get("image"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use RecyclerView and you can set OnclickListener on each items in the list. List view is not popular anymore.
Example of using RecyclerView when set value:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AnyViewHolder view = (AnyViewHolder ) holder;
            view.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Do something
                }

            });
        }
    }
```